# Electron auto-update https error

Tags: https, electron, auto-update

Is there a way to ignore certificate errors if I want to download the new version of the app from a link that uses https?

this is my current error

webException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

and my new version is not downloaded

How to bypass this?

Many thanks